# Different behaviour in WKWebview and Safari regarding CSS

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, wkwebview

There seem te be some subtle differences in the Implementation or configuration between WBWebView and Safari (and SFSafariViewController) that renders a part of the Website I want to display unusable.

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

Basically all that is needed is an "App" that just opens a specific website in fullscreen mode, so no chrome, URLs or additional navigaton buttons are present. The Website works fine on Safari on iOS (and every other (modern) browser on desktop or mobile) but the menu does not when embedded in the App.

All I did was creating a new single view Application in Xcode, drop in a WKWebView and have it load the URL. The part of the page not working is this menu component that is used throughout the site: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/ So basically the user has no way to navigate. While debugging the website it seems like when I push the menu button the menu does not expand like it should because the changed css classes dont get picked up correctly. If I manually toggle the css classes on the menu-element it gets displayed correctly. It makes me wonder if there are some additonal constraints related to WKWebView?

**Can anyone tell me if there are any settings or configurations I can alter that allow the website in WKWebView to behave exactly the same as it would under Safari?**

As far as I understand SFSafariViewController I always get the browser toolbar and navigational elements which I dont want to have in the app, so that is not an option- or is there a way to get rid of that?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :)